# kendo grid multi filterable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I cant  handle a problem and  I need your help.
when ı click a checkbox in checklist to filter , the other checklists should show relationed datas.
İn that picture , I choosed chia other checklist only should show 39 . however , it does not.
how can ı solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not a feature out of the box.  The filterable lists are set on initialization I believe and can not be altered until the whole widget is blown away and recreate.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/@rusev/EHEhO     this link example. this example , I want do ASP.NET MVC .

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss read what you were trying to do.  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes has the code you would need for doing that with their MVC wrappers.